# Microcontroller sending HID keyboard reports works correctly with macOS but not Windows

Tags: windows, usb, stm32, hid

I'm creating a device that sends USB HID Reports from the device to the computer.

```
  if(toggled == 0x01){ // if in toggled state
      if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= 40 && pending == 0x00){ // if 40 ms has passed since last key up hid report
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &report, sizeof(report)); //send report
          pending = 0x01;
      }
      if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= 70 && pending == 0x01 ){ // if 70 ms has passed since last key down hid report and key down report was sent
          previousMillis = currentMillis; // reset timer
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &testReportInactive, sizeof(report));
          pending = 0x00;
      }
  }
```

That is the code that sends the HID report to the computer.

On Windows 10 x64, when changing the toggled state, sometimes the computer will think that the key is still being pressed down and will repeatedly print the character of the key. On macOS, it works correctly and the computer does not think that the key is still being pressed. Any ideas on what to do to fix this on Windows?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, but I would try sending a "no keys pressed" report (which I assume testReportInactive is) whenever the "toggled" flag is changed from 0x01 to 0x00 - even if it may already have been sent.